# Azure cosmosDB default stored procedure did not work

Tags: javascript, azure, stored-procedures, azure-cosmosdb, azure-cosmosdb-sqlapi

When I created the stored procedure, this is the default sample code provided by Azure. My container(Students) is very simple and has only 2 items. The partition key is id.

```
{name: "aaa", id: "1"}

{name: "bbb", id: "2"}
```

Here is the sample stored procedure code provided by Azure CosmosDB.

```
// SAMPLE STORED PROCEDURE
function sample(prefix) {
    var collection = getContext().getCollection();

    // Query documents and take 1st item.
    var isAccepted = collection.queryDocuments(
        collection.getSelfLink(),
        'SELECT * FROM root r',
    function (err, feed, options) {
        if (err) throw err;

        // Check the feed and if empty, set the body to 'no docs found', 
        // else take 1st element from feed
        if (!feed || !feed.length) {
            var response = getContext().getResponse();
            response.setBody('no docs found');
        }
        else {
            var response = getContext().getResponse();
            var body = { prefix: prefix, feed: feed[0] };
            response.setBody(JSON.stringify(body));
        }
    });

    if (!isAccepted) throw new Error('The query was not accepted by the server.');
}
```

Why it always return "no docs found"? I have tried different sql queries like "select * from Students" or "select * from root" or "select * from c" but none of them work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you want to execute stored procedure, you need to pass value of partition key. In your case, you need to pass "1" or "2" as value of partition key(not "id") like this:

[image]

Comment: I can only accept your question in 5 minutes, I cannot accept now. Why do we need to enter partition key when executing the query? I just want to get all items.

Comment: @szastronaut Because stored procedure execution in Cosmos DB  is scoped to a logical partition key, so you can only get the data from one partition. You can't get all items by stored procedure. You can refer to this [doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cosmos-db/stored-procedures-triggers-udfs#scope-of-a-transaction).